# How to download a file from Internet using Java, with URL query parameters

Tags: java, download, query-string

I am writing a Java app that should download a Pdf form here: 
https://forms.business.gov.au/smartforms/servlet/SmartForm.pdf?formCode=RRDAA

I have tried various options, including:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-download-file
- [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

The problem is that the content that's being downloaded when I use those examples, is simply the content of the website that you see when you open the URL.

But I want to download the actual Pdf file, not that website.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

Comment: As per my post, I have looked into the code in this post and all it does is to download the contents of the website but not the Pdf file. So no, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50551419/6821936